# Managing two combobox of which only one must have a value

Tags: c#, combobox

I have this simple code in my DevExpress LookUp control (should be identical with a normal combobox)

```
private void lookUpUsers_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lookUpRolesPréÉdit.EditValue = null;
}

private void lookUpRolesPréÉdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lookUpUsers.EditValue = null;
}
```

The problem is that when I select a value in `lookUpUsers`, is resets the other lookup which then resets `lookUpUsers`. So when I pick a value, both combobox become null. What I want is that when you pick a value in combobox 1, combobox 2 resets its value.

Comment: So, what you're saying is "There can be only one"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
private void lookUpUsers_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(lookUpUsers.EditValue != null)
        lookUpRolesPréÉdit.EditValue = null;
}

private void lookUpRolesPréÉdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(lookUpRolesPréÉdit.EditValue != null)
        lookUpUsers.EditValue = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be an easier way than this, as my knowledge of C# is limited (especially their libraries like you are using them here). Nevertheless, this is an answer that uses no magic provided by libraries:

```
private bool localEdit = false;

private void lookUpUsers_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!localEdit)
     {
        localEdit = true;
        lookUpRolesPréÉdit.EditValue = null;
        localEdit = false;
    }
}

private void lookUpRolesPréÉdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!localEdit)
    {
        localEdit = true;
        lookUpUsers.EditValue = null;
        localEdit = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I've come up with

```
private void lookUpUsers_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isEditFinished)
    {
        isEditFinished = true;
        lookUpRolesPréÉdit.EditValue = null;
    }

    isEditFinished = false;
}

private void lookUpRolesPréÉdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isEditFinished)
    {
        isEditFinished = true;
        lookUpUsers.EditValue = null;
    }

    isEditFinished = false;
}
```

Comment: You're right about my solution not working, but that was because of a silly mistake I made when I didn't 100% understand the intentions of your code yet. You could just have told me, and I would have fixed in a matter of seconds :P